# mysql works, mysqldump doesn't

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, ubuntu

I have mysql 5.5 on my ubuntu 12.04 server. This command:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

works perfectly, but this gives me error:

```
mysqldump -u root -p mydb_name > a.sql
mysqldump: Got error: 2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) when trying to connect
```

In my.cnf file, the socket is set to:

```
socket = /home/mysql/mysql.sock
```

so I have no idea where /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock is coming from. Thanks.

Comment: Did you verify that there are no other `socket` directives further down in `my.cnf`?

Comment: yes i did, that is the only one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When reading the configuration file, the `mysql` command line client only reads configuration directives found in the `[client]` and `[mysql]` sections, while `mysqldump` only uses configuration directives found in the `[client]` and `[mysqldump]` sections.

If your socket directive in the config file is in the `[mysql]` section but not the `[mysqldump]` section then you should move it to the `[client]` section, and this should solve your problem.

So where does `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` come from?  I remember very distinctly, once upon a time, beating my head against the wall repeatedly over that one.

It turns out, Ubuntu compiles their MySQL components from source, and when they do that, they compile them to use `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` unless the configuration file specifies otherwise or the socket is overridden on the command line... so if your `socket` directive isn't in `[client]` that would be one explanation of this behavior.

Comment: Thanx! that was it. I thought [mysqldump] was enough. I didn't even have [client].

Comment: I had to add [mysqldump]
socket=/home/lib/mysql/mysql.sock to my.cnf (centos) then restarted mysqld